# Format xls sheet multi table content in node/Angular/React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, excel, angular

I have an excel sheet that contains multiple table data. I want to format my sheet by adding font color, adding table borders, and apply a formula to a specific column in each table.
Also attached the current excel file and expected excel file's screenshot

Someone pls let me know whether my expected Xls file format is feasible to do in Node/Angular/React and if so suggest the framework to implement this feature.

[image]

Comment: The formula,fonts borders etc will be applied in excel sheet and then you want it to import the data with (formula,fonts borders etc) into React etc. Am I correct?

Comment: No . I im expecting to upload the excel sheet which is present in leftmost part of attached image and need an output as rightmost part of the image